# Error in mysql when saving data

Tags: php, html, sql

I was about to save the data in my table but I got this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the  right syntax to use 
>   near 'div, dep, group, loc, plan, desc, fee, pname, unit, amount,
>   amort)  VALUES ('55' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
$sql=
"INSERT INTO account
       (accnum, mobile, status, assignee, 
          user, position, entitlement, 
          org, div, dep, group, 
          loc, plan, desc, fee, 
          pname, unit, 
          amount, amort)
VALUES
       ('$_POST[accNum]','$_POST[mobNum]','$_POST[stat]','$_POST[assignee]',
        '$_SESSION[userType]','$_SESSION[position]','$_SESSION[entitlement]',
        '$_SESSION[orga]','$_SESSION[divi]','$_SESSION[dept]','$_SESSION[group]',
        '$_SESSION[farm]','$_SESSION[planType]','$_SESSION[promo]',
        '$_SESSION[monthFee]','$_SESSION[phoneType]','$_SESSION[unit]',
        '$_SESSION[amount]','$_SESSION[amort]')";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backticks

```
$sql="INSERT INTO account(`accnum`, `mobile`, `status`, `assignee`, `user`, `position`, `ntitlement`, `org`, `div`, `dep`, `group`, `loc`, `plan`, `desc`, `fee`, `pname`, `unit`, `amount`, `amort`)
VALUES
('$_POST[accNum]','$_POST[mobNum]','$_POST[stat]','$_POST[assignee]','$_SESSION[userType]','$_SESSION[position]','$_SESSION[entitlement]','$_SESSION[orga]','$_SESSION[divi]','$_SESSION[dept]','$_SESSION[group]','$_SESSION[farm]','$_SESSION[planType]','$_SESSION[promo]','$_SESSION[monthFee]','$_SESSION[phoneType]','$_SESSION[unit]','$_SESSION[amount]','$_SESSION[amort]')";
```

[image]

Comment: @imlyn Please accept the answer if it works for you . Thanks for kiss:)

Comment: +1, for even including the keyboard. A truly "Backticks for Dummies".

Answer (score 7):

Because div, group, desc are MySQL keyword.