# MySQL datetime data saving error for 15+ years data

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-8.0

In MySQL 8.0.28 we have a table column named `expiry_date` as `datetime` filed.

When we try to insert data greater than 15 years, it fires

> ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '2038-01-20 03:36:33' for column 'expiry_date' at row 1

For `2038-01-19 03:36:33` date, its inserting to DB.

Table `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`

We can not change data-type as this table is in production system.

What is causing this issue?
Following threads were checked, but not addressing our issue :

[incorrect-datetime-value-while-saving-data-to-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279437/incorrect-datetime-value-while-saving-data-to-mysql)

[incorrect-datetime-value-database-error-number-1292](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806870/incorrect-datetime-value-database-error-number-1292)

[error-in-mysql-when-saving-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995468/error-in-mysql-when-saving-data)

Comment: 32 bits field ?

Comment: here is another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924274/incorrect-datetime-value-for-future-date-in-mysql

Comment: In addition to previous comment please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html , it seems your column is timestamp datatype

Comment: The supported DATETIME range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. There is no such problem on this datatype: https://dbfiddle.uk/3FJdRKs2 Show complete output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;`.

Comment: @P.Salmon TIMESTAMP should fail on both values.